# Drawable Image gives 'No resource found..' but it is in the folder

Tags: android, image, button, resources, drawable

I have the below XML in slider_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@android:drawable/button9patch" />
    ...
</selector>
```

The `android:drawable="@android:drawable/button9patch"` gets the error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable'
>   with value '@android:drawable/button9patch').

However I think I have the file in the right place (I've even put it in all the drawable folders to be sure):

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change like this

```
 android:drawable="@drawable/button9patch"
```

Comment: Fixed it! What a stupid mistake - The tutorial I was following had it like in my post and I just didn't think..